# Intermittent MongoDB Connection Issue: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions

Tags: mongodb, azure-web-app-service, mongodb-.net-driver

I get the following exception thrown occasionally when trying to write documents to my collection.

I am using MongoDB 3.0.7 hosted in mLabs.  Our application is hosted in Azure (as a Web App) and I am using the C# 2.2.3 SDK.

> MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while
>   opening a connection to the server. --->
>   System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An attempt was made to access a
>   socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions
>   191.235.xxx.xxx:54128    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect(IPAddress[] addresses, Int32 port)
>   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect(String host, Int32 port)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.TcpStreamFactory.Connect(Socket
>   socket, EndPoint endPoint, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.TcpStreamFactory.CreateStream(EndPoint
>   endPoint, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.OpenHelper(CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.OpenHelper(CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.Open(CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.ConnectionPools.ExclusiveConnectionPool.AcquiredConnection.Open(CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ClusterableServer.GetChannel(CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Bindings.ServerChannelSource.GetChannel(CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Bindings.ChannelSourceHandle.GetChannel(CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.BulkMixedWriteOperation.Execute(IWriteBinding
>   binding, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.OperationExecutor.ExecuteWriteOperation[TResult](IWriteBinding
>   binding, IWriteOperation'1 operation, CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl'1.ExecuteWriteOperation[TResult](IWriteOperation`1
>   operation, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl'1.BulkWrite(IEnumerable'1 requests,
>   BulkWriteOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionBase'1.InsertOne(TDocument document,
>   InsertOneOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

Comment: were you able to connect mongodb using mongo shell from your local mahine?

Comment: @Astro. Yes. This only happens very occasionally.

Comment: I posted an answer earlier but it was unrelated. Just wanted to say that we've also seen this in Azure Websites connecting Mongo, but it lasted for a day each time (twice, months apart). I'd get in touch with Azure support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens if you hit the sandbox limits. More details in my old answer [Intermittent crashes in Azure Web Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30909733/intermittent-crashes-in-azure-web-application/30921112#30921112)

To know about sandbox limits please refer to https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox

Also came across http://www.freekpaans.nl/2015/08/starving-outgoing-connections-on-windows-azure-web-sites/ which was nicely written on the same subject

***Edit - February 2018***

If you are running in to this issue now, go to **Diagnose and Solve Blade** for your App in the **Azure portal** and check the **TCP Connections** tile. It should give you information about the site consuming the maximum ports and allow you to monitor the state connections instance wide.