# Azure Webjob: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions x.x.x.x:80

Tags: c#, sockets, azure, azure-webjobs, webjob

I know there's a couple questions so far involving this error - but nobody has generated this error yet due to a webjob on Azure.

My code is in the form of a C# `Console Application`. The main part of my code:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("user:password");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("http://xx.xx.xx.xxx/cgi-bin/snapshot.cgi?channel=0");
byte[] myBytes = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
string convertedFromString = Convert.ToBase64String(myBytes);
```

(The code above is called by the `Main` method)

If executed on my local machine it works just fine. If I add this code to an API method used by an App Service (part of an ASP.Net Core project), it also works.

However, when uploaded as an Azure webjob, I get this error:

> An error occurred while sending the request.
>
> Unable to connect to the remote server
>
> An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its
>   access permissions xx.xx.xx.xxx:80

Any ideas on how to get past this? I'm looking for any possible solution/work-around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions xx.xx.xx.xxx:80

Per my understanding, I assumed that you may hit the outgoing connections limitation from [Azure Web App sandbox](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox). Also, I would recommend that you could scale your app hosting plan to larger instance for narrowing this issue.

Additionally, here are some similar issues, you could refer to them:

[Intermittent crashes in Azure Web Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30909733/intermittent-crashes-in-azure-web-application/30921112#30921112)

[Starving outgoing connections on Windows Azure Web Sites](http://www.freekpaans.nl/2015/08/starving-outgoing-connections-on-windows-azure-web-sites/)

Comment: Can you please clarify - how would one fix this issue? Is there a way to change the outgoing connections limitation, or possibly whitelisting an IP address for which it can then make a connection?